# Azure Devops: Completely ignore error in Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a release pipeline in Azure devops where I do the following:

1. Get the values from a (possibly non-existing) keyvault, using the "Azure Key Vault Task" (https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureKeyVaultV1/README.md)
2. Using a python-script, check if a password is set in the key vault
   2.1 If set: save as a variable
   2.2 If not set: Generate a new password and save as variable
3. Run an arm template task to create a keyVault storing the password

The intention here is: 
On the first run of the pipeline, the keyvault is not created, so the input to the python-script is empty*. Then I create a password and set as a variable, and this is saved to the keyVault. On subsequent runs, the key vault exists, and the python script exports the existing passwords. The keyvault value for the password does not change. All is fine

However: the "Azure Key Vault Task" fails when the key vault does not exist. Thus: I need to set the task to "Continue on error". This works fine, except from one detail: The pipeline reports "Partially succeeded", and uses an orange color. From my point of view, this pipeline did not "partially succeed", it did exactly what it was supposed to do. Thus, this warning is misleading to others who might see the output.

So, my question is thus: Is there a way to completely ignore an error in a Pipeline task? I.e: Continue on error without showing "partially succeeded"?

Or is there some other way of doing what I am attempting here? I know I can create an empty keyVault beforehand, but doing this manually defeats the purpose of automating things, and running yet another ARM template seems unnecessary and cumbersome.

- This is another strange issue. I found that when passing a python script an undefined variable, eg. $(myUndefinedVariable), the string '$(myUndefinedVariable)' is actually passed... This is not related to this question though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your approach is just wrong, just shift the retrieval of KV variable to the script and you can control the bevahiour. Moreover, you ask is kinda pointless. "Continue on error" is exactly how its supposed to work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/key-vault?view=azure-python

```
from azure.keyvault import KeyVaultClient, KeyVaultAuthentication
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials

credentials = None

def auth_callback(server, resource, scope):
    credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id = '',
        secret = '',
        tenant = '',
        resource = "https://vault.azure.net"
    )
    token = credentials.token
    return token['token_type'], token['access_token']

client = KeyVaultClient(KeyVaultAuthentication(auth_callback))

secret_bundle = client.get_secret("https://VAULT_ID.vault.azure.net/", "SECRET_ID", "SECRET_VERSION")

print(secret_bundle.value)
```

Comment: Hmm.. I could not find a straightforward way to retrieve KV-values from a python script. Any pointers in that direction?

Comment: check updated answer, you would also need to give the entity you are using for authentication appropriate permissions to the KV

Comment: Thanks, will try!

Comment: This seems to do the trick: https://gist.github.com/atlefren/2c17fa30431ca32ecec669c478c3eebd I also had to run a command line task: pip install azure-keyvault and use the "Service Principal Credentials" task to get connection info. Only problem is that I have to supply tenant in addition..